# publish a release version of web site

Tags: asp.net, versioning

I have a web site that is created in visual studio 2010 through: File > New > Web site (it is not a Web Project).

I want to publish a release version of my web site but there is no 'Release' mode in VS and there is no possibility to add 'Release' mode through Build > Configuration manager.

How can I publish a release version of my web site ??(I can not convert my web site to a Web Project)

**Thank you very mush for your reply.**

Comment: If you do not have other custom dll modules with your project, then what you actually need to change is the web.config and make it for release.

Comment: Do you mean by setting debug="false"? if yes, I did it but I realized that for example javascript resources that are get through webresource.axd are in debug format. I want to pre compile my web site in 'Release' mode without any debug information.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a website project and your using VS 2010 then somewhere amongst the menu options in the menubar across the top should be an option caled COPY WEBSITE (I think its in the website menu).

So you click WEBSITE > COPY WEBSITE then you will see a new tab appear very similar to an FTP kind of interface, with your LOCAL files on the left and the remmote server hosting on the right.

You could use either FTP or Direct upload but the very last time I could only use it via FTP.
(Of course this may be a personal issue and not affect anyone else).

It goes without saying that if you dontr have a server to upload your website to then it can not be "released" as you called it.

Usually the server or hosting is either on your own server or on a remote (Paid for) server with a service provider.

With reference to the photo below....

Area-1 is where you enter the FTP or HTTP address of the server where you will upload te files.
Loacl-Files This shows your completed website files
Remote-Files This shows the files on the server
Controls These button are used to upload or download files to and from the server

Note that you must have an FTP username and password to use FTP/HTTP transfer,
Some hosts may prefer you to use your admin account username and password.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction

[image]